# How to get color of the pixel I clicked on in Unity? Is there a GetPixel alternative that works with floats?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm using a Texture2D to display a map, and I need to get the color of the pixel I clicked on. I used Input.mousePosition to get the float coordinates, but using GetPixel to get the color requires the coordinates to be integers.

I am having trouble with getting GetPixel to find the coordinate that I clicked on.

When using floats and clicking on say, the rightmost side of the texture, I get a number like 27.xxx, but when I cast it to an integer, it displays a coordinate 27 pixels from the leftmost side of the texture. The way floats represent pixels confuses me a great deal, maybe clarifying that would help.

```
public class ProvinceSelectScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material SpriteMain;
    public Color SelectedCol;
    public Color NewlySelectedCol;
    public Texture2D WorldColMap;
    Vector2 screenPosition;
    Vector2 worldPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        WorldColMap = (Texture2D)SpriteMain.GetTexture("_MainTexture");
        NewlySelectedCol = Color.blue;
    }


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y);
        worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);

        
        SelectedCol = WorldColMap.GetPixel(((int)(worldPosition.x)+(WorldColMap.width/2)) , (int)((worldPosition.y)+(WorldColMap.height / 2)));
        

        SpriteMain.SetColor("_SelectedProvince", SelectedCol);
        SpriteMain.SetColor("_NewlySelectedProvince", NewlySelectedCol);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward if it's a UI.Image. Otherwise, you'll have to reverse engineer any nine slicing, sprite sheeting, etc. it gets pretty complicated and is probably too broad for a single answer.

Comment: If have the float value from mousePosition that determines where I clicked on my texture, surely I can transform it into an integer whose position is equivalent to the place I clicked on. Any pointers as to where I can look for an answer?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The `worldPosition` in the question isn't calculated in a way that's useful if you're using a perspective camera or if your camera is pointed any direction but directly forward.

To find the world position of the click, the best way to go about that is to use `Camera.ScreenPointToRay` to calculate the position of the click when intersecting the plane made by the position of the sprite and its local forward.

Either way, a world position does not mean anything to the sprite, which could be positioned anywhere in world space. You should rather use [`transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to calculate the local position you're clicking on. At that point, you can then use the spriterenderer's bounds to convert to normalized form (0-1  originating fromt he bottom-left instead of world unit lengths originating from the center).

But, once you have the local sprite position of the click expressed in normalized form, you can *try* to use [`GetPixelBilinear`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixelBilinear.html) to get the color at the UV of (x,y) of the click. If the sprite is super simple, this MAY work. If it is animated or nine-sliced, or anything else it probably won't, and you'll have to reverse-engineer what UV the mouse is *actually* hovering over.

```
    Camera mainCam;
    SpriteRenderer sr;

    void Start()
    {
        WorldColMap = (Texture2D)SpriteMain.GetTexture("_MainTexture");
        NewlySelectedCol = Color.blue;
        mainCam = Camera.main; // cache for faster access
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); // cache for faster access;
    }


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
    Plane spritePlane = new Plane(transform.position, transform.forward); 
    Ray pointerRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    if (spritePlane.Raycast(pointerRay, out distance))
    {
        Vector3 worldPositionClick = pointerRay.GetPoint(distance);
        Vector3 localSpriteClick = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPositionClick);

        // convert [(-extents,-extents),(extents,extents)] to [(0,0),(1,1)]
        Vector3 localSpriteExtents = sr.sprite.bounds.extents;
        localSpriteClick = localSpriteClick + localSpriteExtents ;

        localSpriteClick.x /= localSpriteExtents.x * 2;
        localSpriteClick.y /= localSpriteExtents.y * 2;

        // You clicked on localSpriteClick, on a very simple sprite (where no uv magic is happening) this might work:
        SelectedCol = WorldColMap.GetPixelBilinear(localSpriteClick.x, localSpriteClick.y);      

        SpriteMain.SetColor("_SelectedProvince", SelectedCol);
    }
```